# JavaScript number error

Tags: javascript, numbers

So I am trying to load an ecommerce checkout but based on the number a user enters:

```
var finalAmount = convert_amount( $('#input').val() );
```

The convert amount is to return the amount * 100 like this:

```
    function convert_amount( amount ) {
        return ( amount * 100 );
    }
```

Ok so here's the problem. For most numbers it works ok, but for some that I have tried it doesn't work correctly. If I enter something like `8.32` then it returns `832` which is perfect. I found that if I enter `8.72` then it returns `872.0000000000001`. I don't get why it is adding the `.0000000000001` onto the number.

Another interesting case is if I put in `8.70` it spits back `869.9999999999999`.

It was recommended to me to try doing `return ( new Number( amount ) * 100 );` but that still did not do the trick.

The reason this is a major problem is because it makes the ecommerce platform reject the amount, saying it is invalid.

Any idea or experiences with this are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Always work in integers when dealing with currency. All prices should internally be represented in pennies. (Times like this make me wish we used Yen...)

Comment: Right, that is basically what I am trying to do. The platform needs the amount in pennies so I need to convert the user entered amount to such a value. I will have to take a look at the article you sent me a link to to see if it answers what I need fully.

Comment: It is more reliable to use string methods (check for decimal place and strip it out), but alternatively just use `Math.round(amount*100)`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks that works perfectly. Keeping the other article bookmarked for further reading. Thanks for such a super fast reply!